# Android Background Service - ADB Touch Commands

Tags: android, service, adb, background-process, tap

I'm trying to get a input tap working for an Android app I'm developing. I'm doing something along these lines:

```
    String call = "/system/bin/input tap 1200 750";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(call);
```

This works fine when clicking on buttons that appear on the screen. However, I would ideally want this application running as a background service. So when I go ahead and type in `am start com.OtherApplication` and then try running these commands, the respective buttons aren't clicked because I'm guessing the UI it is referring to is the older one that I essentially hid when starting the OtherApplication. Anyway I could get input taps working with the current UI? I tried using Instrumentations but that didnt work either.